# Visualisation of binary search tree in terminal

Tags: python, tree, data-visualization, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am looking for a Python tool to visualize a binary search tree and also do insert and delete operations.

Something like this:

```
50
  \
  70
  / \
 /   \
63   90
```

insert(50)
insert(70)
insert(90)
insert(63)

and

delete(70)

```
50
  \
  63
    \
     \
     90
```

Does anyone have something like?

greetz
duffy6

Comment: take a look at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Visualize_a_tree#Python

Comment: Thx, but the styles from your link do not match my style.

Comment: with "style" I mean the vertical style with root in the middle

Comment: Asking for a tool is offtopic here. If you have *code* you are attempting with, and bump into an issue, then it becomes on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I made it like this with binarytree and pybush:

```
# from binarytree import tree
from pybush import  delete, add, Node

eingabe = int(input("First value: "))
tree_root = Node(eingabe)
while True:
    eingabe2 = input("Add Value (i5) or remove value (r3) or exit(e): ")
    aktion = eingabe2[:1]
    wert = int(eingabe2[1:])
    print(aktion, wert)
    if aktion == "i":
        add(tree_root, wert)
    if aktion == "r":
        delete(tree_root, wert)
    print(tree_root)
    if aktion == "e":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create functions for Binary Search Tree, here is the code for insert, find and remove

```
function insert(id, current){
    if (!nodes[id]) nodes[id] = {left: null,right: null, parent: null};   
    if (rootId === null){rootId = id; return;}    
    if (current === undefined) current = rootId;  
    if (id < current)
        if (nodes[current].left === null) nodes[current].left = id;
        else insert(id, nodes[current].left);
    else if (id > current)         
        if (nodes[current].right === null) nodes[current].right = id;        
        else insert(id, nodes[current].right);                
}


function find(id, current){
    if (id == rootId) return nodes[rootId];
    if (id == current) return nodes[current];
    if (current === undefined) current = rootId;  
    if (!nodes[current]) return null;
    if (id < current) return find(id, nodes[current].left);
    else if (id > current) return find(id, nodes[current].right);   
}
```

It is only few lines of code but is doing exactly, what you want.

Created [Code demo](https://code.balkan.app/visualisation-of-binary-search-tree-in-terminal#JS) for you using the methods above

[image]

[image]